# Move between typing boxes of the Entry widgets by using up and down arrow keys

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class Interface_graphique(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.message_1 = Label(self, text="value1")
        self.message_1.grid(row=0, sticky='w')
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.message_2 = Label(self, text="value2")
        self.message_2.grid(row=1, sticky='w')
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

root = Tk()
interface = Interface_graphique(root)
interface.mainloop()
```

I want to type in the Entry widget 'value1' and press the down arrow button to put the cursor in the Entry widget 'value2. Is it possible?

Comment: I imaging it is possible. You would `.bind()` the arrow key to perform the TAB and Shift+TAB functions. Probably with ctypes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` and `focus`:

> **Bind**
>
> Tkinter provides a powerful mechanism to let you deal with events
>   yourself. For each widget, you can bind Python functions and methods
>   to events.
>
> ```
> widget.bind(event, handler)
> ```
>
> If an event matching the event description occurs in the widget, the
>   given handler is called with an object describing the event.

.

> **Focus**
>
> Direct input focus to this widget.
>
> ```
> widget.focus()
> ```
>
> If the application currently does not have the focus this widget will
>   get the focus if the application gets the focus through the window
>   manager.

```
from tkinter import *

class Interface_graphique(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.message_1 = Label(self, text="value1")
        self.message_1.grid(row=0, sticky='w')
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.message_2 = Label(self, text="value2")
        self.message_2.grid(row=1, sticky='w')
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        root.bind('<Down>', self.downKey)
        root.bind('<Up>', self.upKey)

    def downKey(self, event):
        self.entry_2.focus()

    def upKey(self, event):
        self.entry_1.focus()

root = Tk()

interface = Interface_graphique(root)
interface.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, create a binding that moves the focus wherever you want. There are many ways to do that. If you only have two widgets, you can hard-code the widgets. However, tkinter makes it pretty easy to provide a general solution that will always work in every entry widget.

When you create a binding, the bound function will receive an object representing the event. One of the attributes of that object is the widget that captured the event. That widget has a method named `tk_focusNext` that will return the next widget in the standard focus order.

You can add a binding to all Entry widgets that uses this function to change the focus. In the following example, we bind the down-arrow to the `Entry` widget class to call a function which moves the focus

First, create a method that can be bound to the event:

```
    def next_widget(self, event):
        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
        return "break"
```

Next, use this to bind to every entry widget:

```
root.bind_class("Entry", "<Down>", self.next_widget)
```

*or*, bind to each individual entry widget:

```
self.entry_1.bind("<Down>", self.next_widget)
self.entry_2.bind("<Down>", self.next_widget)
```

Comment: I try to do the same thing with a scrolled frame but it doesn't work. 

    def int(root):
        sf = ScrolledFrame(root, True, True) ;
        sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True);
        Label(sf.inner, text="value1").grid(row=0, sticky='w');
        entry_1 = Entry(sf.inner).grid(row=0, column=1);
        root.bind_class("Entry", "<Down>", sf.inner.next_widget);
        frame=sf.inner;
        def next_widget(frame, event): 
             event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus();
             return "break";

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to create a pre-code block with ctrl+K, but I didn't succeed

Comment: For the scrolled frame, I replaced firstly self by sf , then by sf.inner but the two solutions don't work

Comment: @Ing: :"does't work" is a useless phrase, and the comment section isn't the appropriate place to ask a new question or post new code.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to use a list to store your entry fields and then bind each field with a reference to the previous and next field in the list based on index.

The below code will work as needed and with the added benefit of only work while inside of the entry fields. You will not have to worry about using arrow keys when an entry field does not have focus messing with your GUI at all.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
entry_list = []


def move_entry(x):
    entry_list[x].focus()


for i in range(5):
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(root))
    entry_list[-1].pack()

    if i == 0:
        entry_list[-1].bind('<Down>', lambda e, x=i: move_entry(x + 1))
    elif i == 4:
        entry_list[-1].bind('<Up>', lambda e, x=i: move_entry(x - 1))
    else:
        entry_list[-1].bind('<Up>', lambda e, x=i: move_entry(x - 1))
        entry_list[-1].bind('<Down>', lambda e, x=i: move_entry(x + 1))


root.mainloop()
```

As Bryan pointed out `ctypes` is a bit overkill but I wanted to leave this in for anyone curious about `ctypes` just the same.

You can use `ctypes` to perform keyboard events and I copied a well known `ctypes` structure and made a simple tkinter GUI to illustrate how you can bind up and down arrow keys to function like tabs.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import time

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

INPUT_MOUSE = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2

KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008

MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731
VK_TAB = 0x09
VK_SHIFT = 0x10


# C struct definitions

wintypes.ULONG_PTR = wintypes.WPARAM


class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("dx", wintypes.LONG),
                ("dy", wintypes.LONG),
                ("mouseData", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwFlags", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))


class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("wVk", wintypes.WORD),
                ("wScan", wintypes.WORD),
                ("dwFlags", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(KEYBDINPUT, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        # some programs use the scan code even if KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE
        # isn't set in dwFflags, so attempt to map the correct code.
        if not self.dwFlags & KEYEVENTF_UNICODE:
            self.wScan = user32.MapVirtualKeyExW(self.wVk,
                                                 MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 0)


class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("uMsg", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("wParamL", wintypes.WORD),
                ("wParamH", wintypes.WORD))


class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    class _INPUT(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (("ki", KEYBDINPUT),
                    ("mi", MOUSEINPUT),
                    ("hi", HARDWAREINPUT))

    _anonymous_ = ("_input",)
    _fields_ = (("type", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("_input", _INPUT))


LPINPUT = ctypes.POINTER(INPUT)


def _check_count(result, func, args):
    if result == 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args


user32.SendInput.errcheck = _check_count
user32.SendInput.argtypes = (wintypes.UINT,  # nInputs
                             LPINPUT,  # pInputs
                             ctypes.c_int)  # cbSize


# Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode,
                            dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


root = tk.Tk()


def up_key(event):
    PressKey(VK_SHIFT)
    PressKey(VK_TAB)
    ReleaseKey(VK_TAB)
    ReleaseKey(VK_SHIFT)


def down_key(event):
    PressKey(VK_TAB)
    ReleaseKey(VK_TAB)


tk.Entry(root).pack()
tk.Entry(root).pack()
tk.Entry(root).pack()
tk.Entry(root).pack()
tk.Entry(root).pack()

root.bind('<Up>', up_key)
root.bind('<Down>', down_key)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would be nice to know what the downvote is fore. This does work with ctypes.

Comment: ctypes is overkill, and only works on windows. It's not a good general purpose solution.

Comment: I was also looking into a simpler solution using a list to house the entry fields. I will update my answer with additional options.

Comment: @BryanOakley I added a simpler solution that does not involve `ctypes` to my answer. I left the other example for anyone who wanted to take a look just the same.